# Non Self Intersecting Polygons?

Tags: polygons

Given a set of n points is it always possible to construct a non self intersecting polygon?

Comment: Closed polygon with these as only vertices?  We need conditions, take $n$ collinear points.

Comment: Polygon that does what?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I want to know given any random non collinear points is it always possible to construct a non self-intersecting closed polygon.

Comment: An obviously necessary and sufficient condition is that the set of points be "non-reentrant", i.e. no point is inside the convex hull of the other points.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Why is this necessary?  The polygon only needs to be simple, not convex.

Comment: @ErickWong : you’re right, I was only talking about the convex case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose a point $x_0$ of your set and order the other points around $x_0$ counter-clockwise. Label them $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{n-1}$ according to that order. You get a non intersecting polygon and $x_0$ is in its kernel.